# "Text not in expected column". Pyparsing bug?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am scratching my head here:

I get no problems when I do:

```
>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> line1 = pp.Word(pp.nums) + pp.GoToColumn(5)
>>> line1.parseString('1    ')  # four spaces after 1
(['1', ''], {})
```

However, when I add pp.Empty() in between, parsing fails:

```
>>> line1 = pp.Word(pp.nums) + pp.Empty() + pp.GoToColumn(5)
>>> line1.parseString('1    ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1111, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Text not in expected column (at char 5), (line:1, col:6)
```

Why is this happening? Is it a Pyparsing bug?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems like Pyparsing in general has problems when using Empty() with GoToColumn(...).

Comment: You are seeing pyparsing's whitespace-skipping behavior in action. Change Empty() to Empty().leaveWhitespace() and things will work better. What is your intention for inserting Empty()?